# How do I stick a div element to the div above it on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a top header that is fixed and shrinks on scroll. Below that I have a div element (side banner) that has to be centered vertically in the view-pane and has to stick to the top header when I scroll down. I can't get this div element to stick to the top header.

I have tried using the CSS position: sticky but it doesn't work. The issue is the side banner runs over the top header on scroll. I have also tried adding a sticky class that shows up with some javascript but I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't work. PLEASE HELP!

**HTML:**

```
<header id="topBanner">Top Banner</header>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sideBanner" id="sideBanner">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcf2dc;
}

#topBanner {

  background-color: #e9ab18;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;

 }

.sideBanner {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f5d997;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  right: 10px;
}

  .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// FUNCTION TO MAKE TOP HEADER SHRINK ON SCROLL:

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};


function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || 
   document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("topBanner").style.fontSize = "30px";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("topBanner").style.fontSize = "90px";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class sticky in your HTML.

You have created the class in your CSS but you're not applying this class on the HTML.

Comment: Dany, I think Bettag was using `.sticky` but removed it because it wasn't creating the desired behavior (due to it having a `top` property value of `0`.) -- BTW, I assume you know that this would be better posted as a comment than as an answer but you chose to add an answer only because SO won't let you comment directly on questions yet.

Comment: How could I post a comment? I need more than 50 reputation points to post a comment.....

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make by saying "SO won't let you comment directly on questions yet" (trying to help others see why they shouldn't downvote the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Your sticky idea works fine. The tricky part is knowing what `top` value to give it.

Trial and error in Chrome led me to set it to `334px`, but you'd be better off calculating this value dynamically. You could possibly start from `topBanner.offsetHeight` and add in other values (such as padding or margins that may not have been included in the calculated value.)

I also gave topBanner `z-index: 1` in the following snippet (which is almost identical to what you originally posted), to prevent sideBanner from briefly appearing in front of it during rapid scrolling.

(Note: This snippet's behavior is clearer in SO's full-screen view.)

```js
const topBanner = document.getElementById("topBanner");
const sideBanner = document.getElementById("sideBanner");

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  let scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > 50) {
    topBanner.style.fontSize = "30px";
    sideBanner.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    topBanner.style.fontSize = "90px";
    sideBanner.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcf2dc;
}

#topBanner {
  background-color: #e9ab18;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1; /* Positions this element in front of others */
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sideBanner {
  position: absolute;
  background: f5d997;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 334px; /* Hard-coded guess for this value, dynamic would be better */
}
```

```html
<header id="topBanner">Top Banner</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sideBanner" id="sideBanner">
    s <br />
    i <br />
    d <br />
    e <br />
      <br />
    b <br />
    a <br />
    n <br />
    n <br />
    e <br />
    r <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Cat! How would I use the topBanner.offsetHeight property? Right now with 334px it works perfect, but like you said it's probably better to set it dynamically. I'll keep plugging at it but any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: offsetHeight is supposed to return the calculated height of the element, including padding. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight.) You could try putting something like this in the scrollFunction: `let offset = topBanner.offsetHeight; sideBanner.style.top = offset + "px";`. (But I'm not sure if this adds quite enough vertical space, you'd have to play with it and see.)

Comment: I tried the offsetHeight and it doesn't work, it looks like it's setting the height to the banner in the first state and since the banner itself does't have a height but is shrunk by using the font size reduction, I'm guessing that's why it doesn't work. I'm going to try setting banner height instead and see if I can make it work that way. Thanks for helping out @cat!